# Delete GCP bucket object every 7 days

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

We have thousands of GCP bucket in my project in which we want to define some rule to delete object of bucket every 7 days. I need kind of shell script that will run every 7 days and will delete data. As setting up lifecycle of each object is tough manually.

So thats why I need shell script that will do and will put cron tab to do this for me.
Has anyone achieve this earlier?

Thanks,
Mahendra

Comment: Do you need to delete all objects after 7 days or only selected ones, based on a rule?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to define a storage bucket lifecycle policy to automatically delete objects older than 7 days (for example)? Will it be OK for your case?

An overview is here: [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle)

Guidelines are here: [Manage object lifecycles](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/managing-lifecycles)

Comment: The problem here is I have 1000 of buckets and adding deletion policy to every bucket is very tedious. I want to achieve this through shell script that will run on every 7 days and will delete it.

Comment: This can be closed , i got an answer of this.